# Switching between spell checking dictionaries in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, spell-checking

Is there a way to quickly switch between spell checking dictionaries in Sublime Text 2? I don't want to edit the configuration file each time I write in a different language.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`View >> Dictionary >> Select the dictionary you want`

[image: Dictionary menu in view menu]

Comment: Great! How did I miss that? :)